# Visual Studio upgraded my database, now how do I convert it back.

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

I wanted to open my database up using sever explorer in visual studio 2012 and it told me I needed to upgrade my database from 3.5 to 4.0. Now when I deploy my application (WP8 project) it tells me `Incompatible Database Version. If this was a compatible file, run repair. For other cases refer to documentation. [ Db version = 4000000,Requested version = 3505053,File name = mydatabase.sdf ]`. How do I downgrade back to 3.5... I'm using VS2012 - surely if there was a quick upgrade like it did - there is a quick downgrade. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I assume a backup wasn't created by the wizard. You could try using the [SQL Server Compact Toolbox](https://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/) to downgrade from 4.0 to 3.5. There's a [tutorial here](http://erikej.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/how-to-use-exportsqlce-to-migrate-from.html) on how to do it for SQL Server to 4/3.5 but it should be the same for CE 4 to 3.5. The idea is to export your database's information to a file that can then be used to create a `3.5` version of the database.

Before you try and downgrades, create a backup of the database just in case something else happens.